# How to concatenate multiple Flutter TextFormField's in an output Text?

Tags: flutter

The code simplified below uses a Form composed of two TextFormField's. Under the form, a submit button does concatenate the two input fields in an output Text field, The problem is that the output field is neither filled nor updated when the submit button is pressed. How to solve the problem ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Form Validation Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: const MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Create a Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  static const labelStyleTextStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 20);
  static const errorStyleTextStyle = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.red,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 15,
  );

  String? _firstName;
  String? _lastName;
  String? _outputText;

  String? _validateName(String? value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter a non empty name';
    }

    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'First name',
                  labelStyle: labelStyleTextStyle,
                  hintText: 'First name',
                  errorStyle: errorStyleTextStyle,
                ),
                // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                validator: (value) => _validateName(value),
                onSaved: (String? value) => _firstName = value,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Last name',
                  labelStyle: labelStyleTextStyle,
                  hintText: 'Last name',
                  errorStyle: errorStyleTextStyle,
                ),
                // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                validator: (value) => _validateName(value),
                onSaved: (String? value) => _lastName = value,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      _formKey.currentState!.save();
                      _outputText = '$_firstName $_lastName';
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Text(_outputText ?? ''),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that setting the value of _outputText in the onPressed: anonymous function is not sufficient for the updated output text value to be displayed. Calling setState() must be done as well. Here's the modified onPressed function:

```
          onPressed: () {
            // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
              _formKey.currentState!.save();
              setState(() {
                _outputText = '$_firstName $_lastName';
              });
            }
          },
```

[image]